# Represent a number as sum of primes

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am given a large number `n` and I need to find whether it can be represented as sum of K prime numbers.

Ex 9 can be represented as sum of 3 prime number as 2+2+5.

I am trying to use variation of  subset sum but number is too large to generate all primes number till then.

The problem is from the current [HackerRank contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w3/challenges/prime-sum). The restrictions are `1 <= n, K <= 10^12`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For K = 1, the answer is obviously "Yes" iif N is prime

For K = 2, according to the [Goldbach conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), which is verified for N up to around 10^18, the answer is "Yes" iif N is even and N >= 4 or if N - 2 is prime.

The interesting case is K = 3. Obviously if N < 6, the answer is "No" because the smallest number expressible as the sum of three primes is 2 + 2 + 2 = 6.
If N >= 6, then either N - 2 or N - 3 is even and >= 4, so we can apply Goldbach's conjecture again.

So for K = 3, the answer is "Yes" simply iif N >= 6.

Via induction (hint: just use K - 3 times the prime 2), we can show that for K >= 3, the answer is "Yes" iif N >= 2*K, so only the cases K = 1 and K = 2 are non-trivial and require just a simple primality check, e.g. via [Miller–Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) in O(log^4 N).

**EDIT:** As a bonus, this proof also gives a constructive algorithm to output the partition. We use a number of 2's and maybe one 3 to get to K = 2. The tricky K = 2, N even case is not as hard as it looks: We know from [computational verification](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/goldbach.html) of the Goldbach conjecture that for N >= 12, there is a Goldbach partition with a prime < 5200 or so. There are less than 700 such primes, so we can check them all in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Good, but this doesn't give you K primes p_1 + ... + p_K = n . Thumbs up for Miller-Rabin !

Comment: @Brainless Well the task just asks for whether a partition exists. If you want to reconstruct the partition, it all reduces to Goldbach's conjecture as well. From the computational verification we know that there is a partition with one small prime (I guess < 5000 or so for N <= 10^12, according to the chart at http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/goldbach.html), so you can afford to check them all (there are around 700 candidate primes) and test N - p for primality. Still very viable. Of course, unless K is big, which can be the case here, then output size will be a problem.

Comment: The reduction from larger K to K = 3 is just to use (K - 3) times the prime 2. Then you use either 2 or 3 and you're at K = 2 and potentially need to find a Goldberg partition, which I described in the other comment

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called the *prime partitions* of a number. The formula to compute the number of prime partitions of a number is \kappa(n) = \frac{1}{n}\left(\mathrm{sopf}(n) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \mathrm{sopf}(j) \cdot \kappa(n-j)\right); I gave that in LaTeX notation because I don't know how to do it in html. The `sopf(n)` function is the sum of the distinct prime factors of *n*, so `sopf(42) = 12`, since 42 = 2 * 3 * 7, but `sopf(12) = 5`, since 12 = 2 * 2 * 3 but each prime factor is counted once.

I discuss this formula at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/19/prime-partitions/).

Comment: My question is about if there is K prime numbers which form the given number. Not number of prime partition.

Comment: This is smart, but too slow to compute. This takes O(2^n) to compute, and n is very large...

Answer (score 0):

Your input are n and K. There are many cases :

1. K > n : impossible
2. K = n : the K prime numbers are all 1
3. K < n : 4 subcases :

a. n and K are odd

b. n is even, K is odd

c. n is odd, K is even

d. n and K are even

Case a: select any prime p < n and p > 2. The problem reduces to the same problem with input n-p and K-1 instead of n and K respectively, and we fall in case b

Case b: The problem reduces to the same problem with input n-2 and K-1 instead of n and K respectively, and we fall in case d

Case c: idem than b, but we fall in case a instead of d

Case d: if n = 2K, then 2, 2, ..., 2 taken K times is your solution (ie your primes are 2, 2, ..., 2). Otherwise n can be written

```
n = (\sum_{i=1}^{i=K-2} 2 ) + p + q
```

where we add the prime 2 (K-2) times in the sum. Then the problem reduces to the same problem with input n-2(K-2) instead of n and 2 instead of K. But this is Goldbach. You can solve it in O(n sqrt(n)) like this : take p and q both equal to n/2. Increment p and decrease q by 1 at each step until they are both prime.

Comment: In case 2: 1 is not a prime number

Comment: This seems legit, it's still too slow however, but I think it can be improved runtime-wise